# How to add new custom language in moodle

Tags: moodle, language-packs

Hello is there anyone who know that how to **add new custom language in Moodle**??

Note: please i don't want to create language for specific plugin but I want to add new language for whole site.

Let me out from this confusion...

Thank you ['}

Answer (score 1):

you may wish to review this post:

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Starting_a_new_language_pack

Moodle translation is a community effort and is managed at this site:

https://lang.moodle.org/